# friendship Couldn't find User without an ID error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use amistad as a friendship gem.. But i cant get it to work correctly. I use devise as authentication system , my problem when I add click add friend link :

```
    <% unless current_user == @user  %>
   <%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friends_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
   <%end %>
```

I get couldn't find User without an ID error. I cant find the correct links.
Friendships_controller.rb:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @friends = current_user.friends
    @pending_invited_by = current_user.pending_invited_by
    @pending_invited = current_user.pending_invited
  end

  def create
    @Friend = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @friendship_created = current_user.invite(@Friend)
    if @friendship_created
      flash.now[:notice] = "Une demande d'amiti a t envoye  #{@friend.fullname}"
    end
  end

  def approve
    @Friend = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @friendship_approved = current_user.approve(@Friend)
    @friends = current_user.friends
    @pending_invited_by = current_user.pending_invited_by
    flash.now[:notice] = "La demande d'amiti de #{@friend.fullname} a t approuve"
  end

  def remove
    @Friend = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @friendship = current_user.send(:find_any_friendship_with, @Friend)
    if @friendship
      @friendship.delete
      @removed = true
      flash.now[:notice] = "Artık  #{@friend.fullname} ile arkadaşsınız"
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In the link_to you have a `friend_id` param, but you never use it on your controller... I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I fixed the question part. I think it is supposed to use user_id from the user model. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send HTTP POST requests through normal links (without triggering AJAX requests). Replace the link with a form, either manually created through `form_for` and the like, or generated with [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to use `friends_path(:user_id => @user),` instead of `friends_path(:friend_id => @user),`

I still need a good way to solve amistad views.